# Python return class object from own nested method

Tags: python, class-method

I am trying to return a custom class object from a method A that calls a second method C. Both methods A and C are inside the same class called StreetList. My reason for having method C is that there's another method B which also will call C, so I don't want to repeat the code in C.

I want all the properties of the class to be accessible in Jinja HTML, hence the question.

Method C returns the StreetList class object correctly if I put in the correct parameter. But I am doing something wrong and if I call A, A does not return the class StreetList, but just a None object. The parameters and internal code of methods A, B and C are fine as far as I have tested, I have a syntax misunderstanding I think.

The class init method here:

```
class StreetList(object):
    def __init__(self, list_length, street, district, numrange=None, adoption=None, rdclass=None, length=None,
             road_no=None, has_tfl=None, tfl_rd=None, cross_boro=None, boro1=None, boro2=None,
             is_split=None, split=None):
    self.list_length = list_length
    self.street = street
    self.district = district
    self.numrange = numrange
    self.adoption = adoption
    self.rdclass = rdclass
    self.length = length
    self.road_no = road_no
    self.has_tfl = has_tfl
    self.tfl_rd = tfl_rd
    self.cross_boro = cross_boro
    self.boro1 = boro1
    self.boro2 = boro2
    self.is_split = is_split
    self.split = split
```

The method which calls this inside this class:

```
@classmethod
def populate_list(cls, st_list):
    ....
    return cls(list_length, street, district, numrange, adoption, rdclass, length, road_no, has_tfl, tfl_rd,
               cross_boro, boro1, boro2, is_split, split)
```

And the method A that calls the above method C:

```
@classmethod
def get_mainlist(cls, streetpart, name_or_num=""):
....
    return cls.populate_list(mainlist)
```

Tx any tips!

Comment: Where is `cls(list_length, street, ...)` supposed to be getting all those values from in `populate_list(cls, st_list)` exactly? (or is that somewhere in your `...`?)

Comment: Can't reproduce with what's given (plus some assumptions to fill in the blanks); I get a `StreetList` instance back when calling `StreetList.get_mainlist()` Please make your example [complete but minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @glibdud thanks, I now checked above simply on its own, I realise this syntax is OK in Python 3. Problem is somewhere else in long ... code which gets values from MongoDB, thought i had checked thoroughly but obviously not. Will reformulate complete minimal as I can when clearer tx!

Comment: @JonClements thanks, this syntax here is fine, I went back and deleted a ton of comments I had, and it then worked. I think must have been wrong indent somewhere, I guess so many comments made difficult to see I think where the wrong indent was, live and learn I hope, add comments back in at end when everything works...